# CkEditor in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, vuejs2

hi i am using ck editor in my .vue file for now i am

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
        extraPlugins: 'mathjax',
        mathJaxLib: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?
        config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        height: 320,
    } );
});
```

initializing my ckeditor in my home.blade.php in document on ready... but when i am going on a page where ckeditor is placed using router

```
<router-link to="/question/create">
    <a class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="nav-label">New Question</span>
    </a>
</router-link>
```

ckeditor is not being loaded means the text area is not being replaced

[screen shot of editor not being replaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0JCx.png)

but when i am manually reloading the page it gets replaced fine..

[screen shot of editor being replaced after reloading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okr1b.png)

i tried

```
import './../../txt/ckeditor.js
```

at the top of my file but its giving this error...

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.js:72554 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined

i think from one of the editor's dir...
please help me if i am doing it wrong way...

i read that i have call it it mounted hook but i dont know how..

or in the work around what i can do is to reload the page using

```
this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)
```

but i can not find out where to call this, if i call it in mounted hook the page keeps reloading also tried

```
window.location.href
```

but the result is same the textarea is not being replaced with ckditor

Answer (score 0):

I think that use of `$(document).ready(function()...` is the cause. Try using Vue's mounted() method instead.

```
<script>
  mounted () {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
      extraPlugins: 'mathjax',
      mathJaxLib: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?
      config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
      height: 320,
    } );
 }
</script>
```

Comment: but now when i am reloading the page the textarea is not being replaced..@Richard Matsen

Comment: That sounds like you might need `updated()` instead of `mounted()`, or both (in which case move the inner code to a method and call the method from both lifecycle hooks). A bit of testing is needed, but should be straight forward to try the permutations and find one that works.

Comment: i made a function
ckEditor(){
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'content', {
                    extraPlugins: 'mathjax',
                    mathJaxLib: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
                    height: 320
                } );
            },

and then i 

mounted(){
            this.ckEditor()
        },
        updated(){
            this.ckEditor()
        },
on calling in both i am getting 
Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined"
and on calling only in update its not working..@Richard Matsen

Comment: The reference is a bit of a mystery. I'm tempted to guess it's the name of the function, but really would have to see the code of the whole component (including imports) to help.

Comment: Also, when you say 'function' - please confirm that you made a 'method' in the Vue sense of a function on the 'method' object?

Comment: If so, please confirm that you called the method with 'this.ckEditor()'? Best procedure here is if you posted your changes as updates to the question (put a title e.g **Update#1**, etc)